# How to remove disabled attribute from textbox during run time

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

How to remove disabled attribute from textbox in asp.net MVC during run time

In Html format

```
<input id="Yes" type="radio" value="Yes" tabindex="8" name="rdoRecommend" disabled="">

$('#Yes').removeAttr("disabled"); is not working.
```

Comment: jQuery's `removeAttr()` should work fine. How are you executing the JavaScript?

Comment: alert($("#Yes").length) hey check this.. if its return > 0 , then it sould work. else its issue with your jquery selector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use $(document).ready-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#Yes').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HfXBE/

Answer (score 3):

`$('#Yes').removeAttr("disabled");` should work. The question is, are you calling it at the right time? For example did you ensure that the DOM is ready before calling it? Like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Yes').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

As you can see in this [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YWXvh/1/) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put your jquery statement inside the loaded event callback?

http://jsfiddle.net/tWxhh/